# PDFKit in Electron App throws error Module Not Found

Tags: node.js, electron

I was trying to add make an Electron app from an existing CLI app. In the CLI app I was using NodeJS and PDFKit to generate some PDFs.

In Electron, I am using Angular. When I am trying to build my Electron app now, it's throwing error

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module 'pdfkit'
Require stack:
```

In my CLI app, PDFKit works just fine as it's pure NodeJS CLI application. I am aware you can not user pure NodeJS modules in Browser Applications.

Interesting enough, I am able to use `child_process` in my Electron app but not PDFKit.

What could be the problem of this? I tried adding

```
"browser": {
    "child_process": false,
    "pdfkit":false,
    "qr-image":false
  }
```

but it's not working. What are other ways of doing this?